# Google crawling with cookies

Tags: cookies, web-crawler

The content of my site depends of cookies in the request, and when Google crawler bot visits my site it deoesn't index much content, because it does't have the specific cookies in each of its requests.

Is it possible to setup some rule that when the crawler bot is crawling my site it uses the specific cookies?

Answer (score 3):

Googlebot does not honor cookies on purpose -- it has to "see" what anybody else will see on your website, the "smallest common denominator" if you will; otherwise search results would be meaningless to an unknown amount of searchers.

Please google for "Googlebot cookies" to get pointed to discussions and documentations about search engines, how they work and why they work how they work; one solution to your problem might be to implement the "first visit/view free" rule.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the Google crawler has the word "Googlebot" in it's request header. Simply check for that, but be warned that people can spoof this to get access to your site's content as well. As curiousguys stated in the comments, this is generally looked down upon by people who use your site and probably against Google's TOS.

Comment: ok, if i need for example to put cookie in the googlebot request like: locationId=2 (it's cookie), how can i do it ?

Comment: I think the OP wants to inject cookies into each of Googlebots requests... this isn't possible.

Comment: More likely you would have some code before you authentication code that bypasses authentication for GoogleBot. If your template (or whatever) requires user authentication data then you could create a fake user account for GoogleBot and add the cookies to it's header request (which is possible), but kindof hacky.

Comment: "_be warned that people can spoof this to get access to your site's content as well._" be warned that if people can access your site's content _iff_ they change their User-Agent to GoogleBot you are violating Google condition, and if Google notices **you can be removed from Google's index**.