# PHP Session and bots detecting

Tags: php, session

Ok i made a small script, which sets a **$_SESSION[$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']]** the problem, it dont works with bots, if i go to my webpage and make page refresh it works, but it is not working with bots.

When i look in the session dir, i see 1000s of session files, with ips in it, but the session variable is always = **1**, so my thinking, when the bot connects to my site, it always sets a new Session instead of increasing the session variable. Any idea how i can fix this. Here is my code:

```
   <?php
        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION[$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']])){

            $_SESSION[$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']]++;

            if($_SESSION[$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']] % 2 == 0) {
            // DO SOMETHING
}

        } else {
            $_SESSION[$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']] = 1;
        }
    ?>
```

**EDIT FOR JON:**

That script above gets executed on all pages of my site:

The Session Variable: gets build so **$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']** for example is = **127.0.0.1**

so my SESSION variable would be **$_SESSION['127.0.0.1'];**

So when the IP goes, to other pages of my site x,y,1,2,3,5 the **$_SESSION['127.0.0.1']** variable gets an increment of 1

But this dont works for bots.

Jon i thought: SESSION are serverside, so that vars get stored on the server, i dont want set any cookies.

Comment: think you missed a bit. (ie. what you see)

Comment: Your bot will need to respect cookies for sessions to work.

Comment: @MichaelMior im not doing a bot, i want catch bots, which come to my site.

Comment: I see. Well bots are free to ignore cookies, so you won't be able to catch them this way. You would have to store this data persistently somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "fix" this. If someone wants to scrape parts of your site that do not *require* a session being in a specific state (e.g. logged in user) then they will not bother with storing your session id cookies and returning them to you. And without a session id, each time they will look like a new session to you.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Jon, that session gets generated on all pages, i thought sessions are server side. Check my edit in my question please.

Comment: @user1015314: The *data* for the session is stored server-side, but the client tells you which session is theirs with a cookie. You should read up on how HTTP sessions work, as it seems you have some misconceptions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're encountering comes from the solution you invented for another problem. What is the initial problem? Why would you need a session variable? What happens at `// DO SOMETHING`?

Simply [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601734/google-crawling-with-cookies) rely on cookies. It won't work.